# I can not use .toFixed(2) and .toLocaleString() at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I have tried multiple times and in multiple ways to add both total.tofixed(2) total.toLocaleString() to my code but they end up not working or cancelling each other out. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. The below code does not work but if I take out one of the two, it does work.

```
var total = (parseFloat(itemCost.replace(/,/g, '')) + 
(parseFloat(itemCost.replace(/,/g, '')) * salesTax/100));


total = (total) 
total = total.toLocaleString().toFixed(2); 

//display amount
document.getElementById("totalTip").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = total;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `String.prototype.toFixed` doesn't exist - it's [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). Use `toFixed` first, then `toLocaleString` (because `localeString` adds commas and that would invalidate the number if used to construct one).

You need to convert the result of `toFixed` to a number before using `toLocaleString` because `toFixed` creates a string not a number.

```
total = (+total.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString();
```

Comment: I tried this but it cancels each other out, it does not add commas but it does fix it to two places.

Comment: So then remove the `locale` and just use `toString`.

Comment: Maybe there aren't enough digits for commas?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on, it lets me do one or the other and not both at the same time as in total.toFixed(2); works in the code or if I delete that and put total.toLocaleString(); that also works but not when added together There are enough numbers for commas so I'm really not sure.

Comment: Yes - that will do the `toFixed`. What *exactly* do you want to happen?

Comment: total = total.toLocaleString(); but that way did not work either.

Comment: I am displaying a dollar amount so I need commas and two decimal places as in $1,950.25 etc.. I either get two decimal places or I get commas and not both.

Comment: The amount changes based on the inputs

Comment: Found the problem - see my edited answer @everythingEquals42.

Comment: That did not work either, it causes it to be fixed two places but again no commas. Thanks for your efforts. I think it's futile at this point.

Answer (score 0):

On reading the documentation for [Number#toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), which has one or two optional arguments, using those arguments will get you what you want

```js
let number = 12345678.123456

console.log(number.toLocaleString('en',{minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2}));
```

or, to display in clients locale

```js
let number = 12345678.123456

console.log(number.toLocaleString(navigator.language,{minimumFractionDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits:2}));
```